# CDI injection in JASPIC ServerAuthModule doesn't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi, jaspic

Using Wildfly 11 Final on Java 10.

I have JASPIC implementation that by itself works as it should. I need to hook it to a DB so i can do authentication in `public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject clientSubject, Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException {...}` . However `@Resource(mappedName="java:jboss/datasources/someDB") javax.sql.DataSource db;` is always `null` for `db`.

CDI works as expected for an arbitrary Servlet class in the same WAR archive - if i put that exact line in a Servlet class, it gives a `DataSource` object.

I work around this with manual lookup via `private static InitialContext ic;` But i need CDI for other global things. Has anyone faced such problem? `WEB-INF/beans.xml` has a `bean-discovery-mode="all"` attribute in the `beans` element.

```
public class SrvAuthModuleImpl implements ServerAuthModule {

@Resource(mappedName="java:jboss/datasources/someDB") javax.sql.DataSource db; //always null
private static InitialContext ic; //workaround via manual lookup

private CallbackHandler handler;
private Class<?>[] supportedMessageTypes = new Class[] {HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class};

@Override
public void initialize(MessagePolicy requestPolicy, MessagePolicy responsePolicy, CallbackHandler handler, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") java.util.Map options) throws AuthException {
    this.handler = handler;
}

@Override
public AuthStatus validateRequest(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject clientSubject, Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException {

    try (
        Connection c = getDb().getConnection(); //works
        // Connection c = db.getConnection(); //db is null, exception thrown
    ) {

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }

    return AuthStatus.SUCCESS;
}

@Override
public Class<?>[] getSupportedMessageTypes() {return supportedMessageTypes;}
@Override
public AuthStatus secureResponse(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject serviceSubject) throws AuthException {return AuthStatus.SEND_SUCCESS;}
@Override
public void cleanSubject(MessageInfo messageInfo, Subject subject) throws AuthException {}

private static javax.sql.DataSource getDb() {
    try {
        if (ic == null) {
            synchronized(TestServerAuthModule.class) {
                if (ic == null) {
                    ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
                }
            }
        }
        return (javax.sql.DataSource)ic.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/someDB");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected. JASPIC is older than Resource Injection or CDI and does not support either.

In Java EE 7, you can use something like

```
CDI.current().select(MyBean.class).get()
```

to get hold of CDI beans in unmanaged contexts.

Another option is [Soteria](https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria), the reference implementation of the Java EE 8 Security API, which also works on WildFly 11.